# Gnome Shell Extension Manager 0.4: when searching, nothing comes

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

When using the gnome shell extension manager, I usually was able to search for extensions and select and install them. Now, on all 3 of my devices, 2 ThinkPads (one of them running Debian 12, Other one Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS) and one Asus Gaming laptop (ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS), it suddenly stopped working. The version is 0.4.

Now when I search for something, this comes:
[image]

and then, one letter later:
[image]

usually it would show the extension "caffeine", but now it doesn't.

How can I fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to type in full extension name. i.e. 'caffeine'? Even when searching on extensions web page ([extensions.gnome.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCgDd.png)) it shows this extension only when you type in its full name.

It worked the same for me in Extensions Manager:

[image]

Comment: That works, but its still kinda annoying, because it used to work that I didn't have to put in the whole name. :/

Comment: I totally agree - this behaviour is counter-intuitive and not something you expect from a search engine these days. Perhaps this issue should be brought up on [Gnome forum](https://discourse.gnome.org/)?